# How to validate the text inside of each index in selenium web driver using Quantum frawework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In the html tag below, I would like to check first if "data index=1"
Then if yes, I will then check if that cardbox must contain health, then the product and policy #.

How should I do this in selenium webdriver using quantum framework.

Thanks in advance. Below I paste the htm tag:

```
<div _ngcontent-c23="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 space-column ng-star-inserted" data-index="0">
    <cws-cardbox _ngcontent-c23="" _nghost-c28="" class="Investment0" ng-reflect-ng-class="Investment0" ng-reflect-status="A"><div _ngcontent-c28="" class="card-status active" ng-reflect-klass="card-status" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
</div>
<div _ngcontent-c28="" class="card-box">

          <div _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy">
            <span _ngcontent-c23="" class="planType">Investment</span>
            <span _ngcontent-c23="" class="product">
              Inheritance
            </span>
            <div _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy-no">
                <label _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy-label">
                  Policy No.:
                </label>
                <span _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy-value">8000000001</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div _ngcontent-c23="" class="divider"></div>

          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
          <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy-content ng-star-inserted">

          </div>

</div>

</cws-cardbox>
  </div>
```

Below is my code:

How to ensure that the validation will only loop into the div tag data_index0?

```
@QAFTestStepProvider
public class cwsPolicyCardStepDef{

        @QAFTestStep(description = "validate data index")
        public void dataIndexValidation() {
            QAFExtendedWebElement dataIndex0 = new QAFExtendedWebElement("xpath_of_data_index_0");
            QAFExtendedWebElement planType = new QAFExtendedWebElement("xpath_of_plan_type");

            dataIndex0.verifyPresent("data index 0 is present...");
            planType.verifyPresent("plan type 'Investment' is inside data index 0... ");


        }
}
```

I am also trying to find an attribute inside of an element but I am not sure though how this works. below is the function:

```
public boolean isAttribtuePresent(WebElement element, String attribute) {
    Boolean result = false;
    try {
        String value = element.getAttribute(attribute);
        if (value != null){
            result = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual HTML. You've somehow posted HTML without the <>s which makes it hard to read and understand... and the indent is not correct. Where is your code? and the results of running it?

Comment: Hi JeffC - I do not have code yet that is why I am asking how to code it. I am trying to paste the actual htm but it is displaying the output, not the htm tags..

Comment: SO is for asking technical questions to help get you unstuck... not to write code for you. You will need to do some research and make a reasonable attempt at writing the code yourself and then come back and ask questions after you get stuck and can't get yourself unstuck with googling and more research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already resolved the issue and approach...

Below is the code I made...

```
    @QAFTestStep(description = "user validate that policy card in desktop {0} contains plan type {1}, policy product {2}, policy value {3}, policy label {4} and status is {5} highlighted in {6}")
    public void userValidateEachPolicyCards(String dataIndex, String planType, String policyProduct, String policyValue, String policyLabel, String policyStatus, String policyStatusColor) {

        String sGetCardBoxStatus;
        String sGetCardBoxColor;
        String sGetCardBoxPlanTypeValue;
        String sGetCardBoxProduct;
        String sGetCardBoxLabel;
        String sGetPolicyNumber;

        sGetCardBoxColor = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("*//div[@data-index = '"+ dataIndex +"']/descendant::div[contains(@class, 'card-status')]")).getCssValue("background-color"); //.getAttribute("background-color");
        if((Color.fromString(sGetCardBoxColor).asHex()).equals(policyStatusColor)) {
            Reporter.log("Passed: Policy Status Color: "+ policyStatusColor, MessageTypes.Pass);
        }else {
            Reporter.log("Failed: Policy Status Color is not "+ policyStatusColor, MessageTypes.Fail);
        }

        sGetCardBoxStatus = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("*//div[@data-index = '"+ dataIndex +"']/descendant::div[contains(@class, 'card-status')]")).getAttribute("class");
        if(sGetCardBoxStatus.equals(policyStatus)) {
            Reporter.log("Passed: Policy Status: "+ policyStatus, MessageTypes.Pass);
        }else {
            Reporter.log("Failed: Policy Status is not "+ policyStatus, MessageTypes.Fail);
        }

        sGetCardBoxPlanTypeValue = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("*//div[@data-index = '"+ dataIndex +"']/descendant::span[contains(@class, 'planType')]")).getText();
        if(sGetCardBoxPlanTypeValue.equals(planType)) {
            Reporter.log("Passed: Plan Type: "+ planType, MessageTypes.Pass);
        }else {
            Reporter.log("Failed: Plan Type is not "+ planType, MessageTypes.Fail);
        }

        sGetCardBoxProduct = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("*//div[@data-index = '"+ dataIndex +"']/descendant::span[contains(@class, 'product')]")).getText();
        if(sGetCardBoxProduct.equals(policyProduct)) {
            Reporter.log("Passed: Policy Product: "+ policyProduct, MessageTypes.Pass);
        }else {
            Reporter.log("Failed: Policy Product is not "+ policyProduct, MessageTypes.Fail);
        }

        sGetCardBoxLabel = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("*//div[@data-index = '"+ dataIndex +"']/descendant::label[contains(@class, 'policy-label')]")).getText();
        if(sGetCardBoxLabel.equals(policyLabel)) {
            Reporter.log("Passed: Policy Label: "+ policyLabel, MessageTypes.Pass);

            sGetPolicyNumber = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("*//div[@data-index = '"+ dataIndex +"']/descendant::span[contains(@class, 'policy-value')]")).getText();
            if(sGetPolicyNumber.equals(policyValue)) {
                Reporter.log("Passed: Policy Number: "+ sGetPolicyNumber, MessageTypes.Pass);
            } 
        else {
                Reporter.log("Failed: Either Policy Label or Policy Number is not found...", MessageTypes.Fail);
            }
        }
    }
}
```